# Disable guest checkout

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I have a problem with my clients from the website. I want to make them to sign up, so I want to disable the guest checkout, they should could buy only if they have an account.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @bursuc Andrei: can you help us to enable guest checkout on WP site having Woo Commerce. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1:** Checkout - this image disable checkout

[image: Checkout this image disable checkout]

**Option 2:** Add this code of function.php file or a custom plugin

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_enable_guest_checkout','conditional_guest_checkout_based_on_product' );
function conditional_guest_checkout_based_on_product( $value ) {
    $restrict_ids = array( 1, 2, 3 ); // Replace with product ids which cannot use guest checkout
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
        foreach ( $cart as $item ) {
            if ( in_array( $item['product_id'], $restrict_ids ) ) {
                $value = "no";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

**Option 3 (Update):** Checkout - this image disable checkout for guests in the current version of this update which is Woocommerce Version 3.6.5
I tried and it's worked for me. So now the guest have to login or sign up to continue.
[image: Checkout this image disable checkout]

Answer (score 1):

Allow customers to place orders without an account can be enable or disable in Account&privacy tab in woocommerce -> settings